# getting the row and column numbers from coordinate value in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to covert a coordinate value in excel to a row number and column number in openpyxl.

For example if my cell coordinate is D4 I want to find the corresponding row and column numbers to use for future operations, in the case row = 3, column = 3. I can get the row number easily using  `ws.cell('D4').row` which returns `4` then it's just a matter of subtracting 1. But a similar argument `ws.cell('D4').column` returns `D` and I don't know how to easily get this into int form for subsequent operations. So I turn to you wise folks of stackoverflow. Can you help me?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

What you want is `openpyxl.utils.coordinate_from_string()` and `openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string()`

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
xy = coordinate_from_string('A4') # returns ('A',4)
col = column_index_from_string(xy[0]) # returns 1
row = xy[1]
```

Comment: One other question Adam, where can I find out about these different commands? The online documentation that I've been able to find, http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/index.html is pretty sparse and does not contain the functions you listed.

Comment: Not much on documentation - it was built off of phpexcel - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com, and there is significant overlap.  For a python project, the code is structured quite well - there is a lot you can find just looking through the unittests in the source.

Comment: For anyone using the most recent version of openpyxl (version 2.3.1 circa 11/20/2015), keep in mind that some of the function definitions have been moved to different parts of the package. "coordinate_from_string" and "column_index_from_string" must now be imported "from openpyxl.utils". See the documentation [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/api/openpyxl.utils.html)

Comment: not sure when this started but at least as of ```openpyxl-utilities==0.5``` (as of 2019), you would import by using ```from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string```

Answer (score 89):

openpyxl has a function called **get_column_letter** that converts a number to a column letter.

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
print(get_column_letter(1))
```

1 --> A

50 --> AX

1234-- AUL

I have been using it like:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

#create excel type item
wb = Workbook()
# select the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

counter = 0
for column in range(1,6):
    column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
    for row in range(1,11):
        counter = counter +1
        ws[column_letter + str(row)] = counter

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: The OP wanted to convert column letters into index numbers, but going in reverse is more difficult and less obvious. Great solution for handling that problem nice and clean.

Comment: This is great to set column width and other column_dimensions properties across range of Excel columns, since openpyxl column_dimensions[x].width seems only to accept string letter value of the column, not an integer.

Answer (score 8):

There is a method in the [openpyxl.utils.cell](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html) module that meets the desired functionality. The method, [openpyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_to_tuple()](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_to_tuple), takes as input the alphanumeric excel coordinates as a string and returns these coordinates as a tuple of integers.

```
openpyxl.utils.cell.coordinate_to_tuple('B1')
>> (1, 2)
```

This provides a cleaner, one-line solution using the specified lib.

Comment: Very short line answer which I needed

Answer (score 3):

This is building off of Nathan's answer. Basically, his answer does not work properly when the row and/or column is more than one character wide. Sorry - I went a little over board. Here is the full script:

```
def main():
    from sys import argv, stderr

    cells = None

    if len(argv) == 1:
        cells = ['Ab102', 'C10', 'AFHE3920']
    else:
        cells = argv[1:]

    from re import match as rematch

    for cell in cells:
        cell = cell.lower()

        # generate matched object via regex (groups grouped by parentheses)
        m = rematch('([a-z]+)([0-9]+)', cell)

        if m is None:
            from sys import stderr
            print('Invalid cell: {}'.format(cell), file=stderr)
        else:
            row = 0
            for ch in m.group(1):
                # ord('a') == 97, so ord(ch) - 96 == 1
                row += ord(ch) - 96
            col = int(m.group(2))

            print('Cell: [{},{}] '.format(row, col))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Tl;dr with a bunch of comments...

```
# make cells with multiple characters in length for row/column
# feel free to change these values
cells = ['Ab102', 'C10', 'AFHE3920']

# import regex
from re import match as rematch

# run through all the cells we made
for cell in cells:
    # make sure the cells are lower-case ... just easier
    cell = cell.lower()

    # generate matched object via regex (groups grouped by parentheses)
    ############################################################################
    # [a-z] matches a character that is a lower-case letter
    # [0-9] matches a character that is a number
    # The + means there must be at least one and repeats for the character it matches
    # the parentheses group the objects (useful with .group())
    m = rematch('([a-z]+)([0-9]+)', cell)

    # if m is None, then there was no match
    if m is None:
        # let's tell the user that there was no match because it was an invalid cell
        from sys import stderr
        print('Invalid cell: {}'.format(cell), file=stderr)
    else:
        # we have a valid cell!
        # let's grab the row and column from it

        row = 0

        # run through all of the characters in m.group(1) (the letter part)
        for ch in m.group(1):
            # ord('a') == 97, so ord(ch) - 96 == 1
            row += ord(ch) - 96
        col = int(m.group(2))

        # phew! that was a lot of work for one cell ;)
        print('Cell: [{},{}] '.format(row, col))

print('I hope that helps :) ... of course, you could have just used Adam\'s answer,\
but that isn\'t as fun, now is it? ;)')
```

Comment: Overboard maybe, but a clean way to slice up coordinates with rematch.  Definitely groundwork for other problems converting coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but the answer is not correct!

**dylnmc** method was a good one, but has some errors. The calculated row for cell coords like "AA1" or "AAB1" is not correct.

Below is the corrected version as a function.

**NOTE:** This function returns the real coordinated. If you want to use it for example in ExcelWriter, both ROW and COL should be deducted by one. So replace the last line with **return(row-1,col-1)**

For example 'AA1' is [1,27] and 'AAA1' is [1,703]; but the python must have them as [0,26] and [0,702].

```
import re

def coord2num(coord):
    cell = coord.lower()

    # generate matched object via regex (groups grouped by parentheses)
    m = re.match('([a-z]+)([0-9]+)', cell)

    if m is None:
        print('Invalid cell: {}'.format(cell))
        return [None,None]
    else:
        col = 0
        for i,ch in enumerate(m.group(1)[::-1]):
            n = ord(ch)-96
            col+=(26**i)*(n)

        row = int(m.group(2))

    return[row,col]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like newer versions of [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) support `cell.col_idx`, which provides a 1-based column number for the cell in question.

So `ws.cell('D4').col_idx` should give you 4 instead of `D`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the column number

```
col = "BHF"
num = 0
for i in range(len(col)):
    num = num + (ord(col[i]) - 64) * pow(26, len(col) - 1 - i)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without using any library:

```
def col_row(s):
    """ 'AA13' -> (27, 13) """

    def col_num(col):
        """ 'AA' -> 27 """
        s = 0
        for i, char in enumerate(reversed(col)):
            p = (26 ** i)
            s += (1 + ord(char.upper()) - ord('A')) * p
        return s

    def split_A1(s):
        """ 'AA13' -> (AA, 13) """
        for i, char in enumerate(s):
            if char.isdigit():
                return s[:i], int(s[i:])

    col, row = split_A1(s)
    return col_num(col), row

col_row('ABC13')
# Out[124]: (731, 13)
```

Answer (score -4):

You could just use pure Python:

```
cell = "D4"
col = ord(cell[0]) - 65
row = int(cell[1:]) - 1
```

This uses the `ord` function which takes a character and returns its ASCII code. In ASCII the letter `A` is 65, `B` is 66 and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately this doesn't work in the case of columns greater than Z for example AD.