# Finding Excel cell reference using Python

Tags: python, excel, match, cell

[Here is the Excel file in question:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwVen.png)

Context: I am writing a program which can pull values from a PDF and put them in the appropriate cell in an Excel file.

Question: I want to write a function which takes a column value (e.g. 2014) and a row value (e.g. 'COGS') as arguments and return the cell reference where those two intersect (e.g. 'C3' for 2014 COGS).

```
def find_correct_cell(year=2014, item='COGS'):
    #do something similar to what the =match function in Excel does
    return cell_reference #returns 'C3'
```

[I have already tried using openpyxl like this to change the values of some random empty cells where I can store these values:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N9RE.png)

```
    col_num = '=match(2014, A1:E1)'
    row_num = '=match("COGS", A1:A5)'
```

But I want to grab those values without having to arbitrarily write to those random empty cells. Plus, even with this method, when I read those cells (F5 and F6) it reads the formulae in those cells and not the face value of 3.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have Python variables showing the lists you are trying to match? E.g., if `dates = [2014, 2015, 2016]` then `dates.index(2014)` will give `0`. But we need more info on what form your data are in now in order to answer this question.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm just trying to take a spreadsheet and find out the column of a certain year and the row of a certain item so I know the location of where I should put data for that item in that year. Does that make better sense?

Comment: It would help to be more explicit about where your data is stored, how it is organized, and what tools you are using, e.g., "Years are listed in cells A1:E1 of an Excel workbook, and products are listed in cells A1:A5. I am using openpyxl to read and write the workbook, and I need to create an 'A1'-style reference for the cell whose row matches the specified product and column matches the specified year." (I had to read between the lines to realize you are using openpyxl and that the lookup lists are located in particular ranges in the Excel workbook.) I've posted an answer below.

Comment: (Sorry, I probably should have looked at your example spreadsheet to figure out what you were asking for! That's what I get for commenting before I've had my coffee!)

Answer (score 1):

There are a surprising number of details you need to get right to manipulate Excel files this way with openpyxl. First, it's worth knowing that the xlsx file contains two representations of each cell - the formula, and the current value of the formula. openpyxl can return either, and if you want values you should specify `data_only=True` when you open the file. Also, openpyxl is not able to calculate a new value when you change the formula for a cell - only Excel itself can do that. So inserting a MATCH() worksheet function won't solve your problem.

The code below does what you want, mostly in Python. It uses the "A1" reference style, and does some calculations to turn column numbers into column letters. This won't hold up well if you go past column Z. In that case, you may want to switch to numbered references to rows and columns. There's some more info on that [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902621/getting-the-row-and-column-numbers-from-coordinate-value-in-openpyxl). But hopefully this will get you on your way.

Note: This code assumes you are reading a workbook called 'test.xlsx', and that 'COGS' is in a list of items in 'Sheet1!A2:A5' and 2014 is in a list of years in 'Sheet1!B1:E1'.

```
import openpyxl

def get_xlsx_region(xlsx_file, sheet, region):
    """ Return a rectangular region from the specified file.
    The data are returned as a list of rows, where each row contains a list 
    of cell values"""

    # 'data_only=True' tells openpyxl to return values instead of formulas
    # 'read_only=True' makes openpyxl much faster (fast enough that it 
    # doesn't hurt to open the file once for each region).
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_file, data_only=True, read_only=True)  

    reg = wb[sheet][region]

    return [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in reg]

# cache the lists of years and items
# get the first (only) row of the 'B1:F1' region
years = get_xlsx_region('test.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'B1:E1')[0]
# get the first (only) column of the 'A2:A6' region
items = [r[0] for r in get_xlsx_region('test.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'A2:A5')]

def find_correct_cell(year, item):
    # find the indexes for 'COGS' and 2014
    year_col = chr(ord('B') + years.index(year))   # only works in A:Z range
    item_row = 2 + items.index(item)

    cell_reference = year_col + str(item_row)

    return cell_reference

print find_correct_cell(year=2014, item='COGS')
# C3
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a translated VBA solution as the [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) function can adequately handle your needs. Python can access the Excel VBA Object Library using a COM interface with the `win32com` module. Please note this solution assumes you are using Excel for PC. Below includes the counterpart VBA function.

**VBA** Function  *(native interface)*

If below function is placed in Excel standard module, function can be called in spreadsheet cell `=FindCell(..., ###)`

```vb
' MATCHES ROW AND COL INPUT FOR CELL ADDRESS OUTPUT
Function FindCell(item As String, year As Integer) As String    
    FindCell = Cells(Application.Match(item, Range("A1:A5"), 0), _
                     Application.Match(year, Range("A1:E1"), 0)).Address    
End Function

debug.Print FindCell("COGS", 2014) 
' $C$3
```

**Python** Script *(foreign interface, requiring all objects to be declared)*

Try/Except/Finally is used to properly close the Excel process regardless of script success or fail.

```
import win32com.client

# MATCHES ROW AND COL INPUT FOR CELL ADDRESS OUTPUT
def FindCell(item, year):
    return(xlWks.Cells(xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Match(item, xlWks.Range("A1:A5"), 0), 
                       xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Match(year, xlWks.Range("A1:E1"), 0)).Address)

try:
    xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:/Path/To/Workbook.xlsx')
    xlWks = xlWbk.Worksheets("SHEETNAME")

    print(FindCell("COGS", 2014))
    # $C$3

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:    
    xlWbk.Close(False)
    xlApp.Quit

    xlWks = None
    xlWbk = None
    xlApp = None
```