# How to get cell number of an excel using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there a way to access cell number of an excel cell in Pandas?
I am able to access cell value by iterating over rows and columns but I want to get the cell number for that particular iteration.

Eg: A21, where A21 is the cell number, A is the column letter and 21 is the row number.

I need the column letter to pass it to hyperlink

Comment: openpyxl is your friend for this use case

Comment: Could you please give me an example or a sample code to refer to?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902621/getting-the-row-and-column-numbers-from-coordinate-value-in-openpyxl)

Comment: Yes this get_column_number() works. Thank you