# sort string with number python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python dictionary like this:

```
dict = {"A1":"value1", "C1":"value3", "B1":"value2", "C2":"value6", "A2":"value4", "B2":"value5", "B10":"value7", "C10":"value8"}
```

(actually, keys are Excel cells address)

and I want to sort the dictionary like this:

```
sorted_dict = {

"A1":"value1",

"B1":"value2",

"C1":"value3",

"A2":"value4",

"B2":"value5",

"C2":"value6",

"B10":"value7",

"C10":"value8"

}
```

can anybody help me?

thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear... Are you sorting on the values rather than the keys?

Comment: If you want to sort it by values then `dict(sorted(dict_.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))` this will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: @OldBill sorting on keys, ignore the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, dont name your variable with a reserved word `dict`

here, i sort first by the number, then letter `A1`

```
l = list(mydict.keys())
l.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[1:]), x[0]))
mydict = {k: mydict[k] for k in l}
mydict
```

result:

```
{'A1': 'value1',
 'B1': 'value2',
 'C1': 'value3',
 'A2': 'value4',
 'B2': 'value5',
 'C2': 'value6',
 'B10': 'value7',
 'C10': 'value8'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the sort is based on the values in which case:

```
import re

data = {"A1":"value1", "C1":"value3", "B1":"value2", "C2":"value6", "A2":"value4", "B2":"value5", "B10":"value7", "C10":"value8"}

rep = re.compile('([A-Za-z]*)(\d+)')

def cmp(x):
    _, value = x
    a, n = rep.findall(value)[0]
    return int(n), a


print(dict(sorted(data.items(), key=cmp)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'A1': 'value1', 'B1': 'value2', 'C1': 'value3', 'A2': 'value4', 'B2': 'value5', 'C2': 'value6', 'B10': 'value7', 'C10': 'value8'}
```

**Note:**

The assumption here is that the values are a sequence of letters followed by a sequence of digits

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to sort by Excel row number and then column number, as derived from the cell address. To do that, you will need to convert the A1-style cell address into a sortable key. This is tricky because you can't just split or swap the alpha and numeric parts, since that won't handle columns like 'AA' correctly. Here is some code that should work, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902801/3830997.

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string,  column_index_from_string

def row_col(item):
    # item is a tuple of cell ref, value
    coord = coordinate_from_string(item[0])
    col = column_index_from_string(coord[0])
    row = coord[1]
    return (row, col)

my_dict = {"A1":"value1", "C1":"value3", "B1":"value2", "C2":"value6", "A2":"value4", "B2":"value5", "B10":"value7", "C10":"value8"}

new_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=row_col))
```

Answer (score -1):

For new output
this will work

```
print(dict(sorted(dict_.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])))
```